# I'm not able to add a 3-d look to my data in Qlik

Tags: visualization, qlikview, qliksense

[THIS IS WHAT IM SEARCHING FOR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zE1iH.png)

I downloaded Qlik for 30 days to see if I can use it to make 3-d bar charts.

Not the x-y-z but the x-y inputs that have the 3-d "look" to them.

I see that in order to have those, I need to have either grouped or stacked data.

What exactly does that mean and once I place that within Qlik, how do I find those settings?

The data I have now looks like [THIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsF7M.png)

How can I adjust my data so I can get something like [THIS?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XerT.png)

Answer (score 0):

The first and last screenshots you've attached are from [QlikView](https://www.qlik.com/us/products/qlikview), the previous generation of analytics product from [Qlik](https://qlik.com). [Qlik Sense](https://www.qlik.com/us/products/qlik-sense) is the newer generation that effectively replaced QlikView a 5+ years ago. The 3D look is not achievable in native Qlik Sense as it was given a modern look and feel. It would no doubt be possible to build it into an extension, but I'd question [whether you should](https://medium.com/@purohitpraveen/data-vizualization-why-3d-charts-are-a-terrible-idea-32657fbb928e).

Comment: Is Qlikview still something that can be implemented today? Is it worth it? My workplace is looking for new tools and we use Excel at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a 3D bar chart, the bars in the foreground can hide those in the background. Also, the 3rd dimension typically creates two horizontal lines at the top of each bar, making it more difficult to judge height. I steer away from 3D images where possible as they can confuse the users.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).